# TypeScript Cannot find name 'hideInstallPromotion'

Tags: typescript

I'm following this guide https://web.dev/customize-install/ to install a PWA with a button but TypeScript doesn't like `hideInstallPromotion()`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from './button';

function InstallPWA() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const install = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    hideInstallPromotion(); // TyoeScript doesn't like this? Why?
    console.log('install');
  };

  return (
    <div className='InstallPWA'>
      <Button onClick={install} >Install<button/>
    </div>
  );
}

export { InstallPWA };
```

Comment: Where is that method defined?

Comment: if you have a peek at the link I provided it doesn't define it, I'm guessing this is something the browser provides? I'm not sure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is described as hiding the installation button. So don't call the exact same function here. You have to find a way to hide the button there.